# Cannot make .Offset to work in excel vba macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck, and would like a little hlep. I'm trying to get a qty on Column D12, d14, d16 .... to d42. Than multiply this qty by a value. the value sheet look like this.

### Value Sheet

```
         A        B          C
       ItemName   Quality   Confort
  1     Chair     2          1
  2     Bed       0          3
  3     Table     1          1
```

### Quantity Sheet

```
      A      B         C      D
            ItemName        QTYColumn
12    ..    Table             2
13 
14    ..    Chair             5 
15          
16    ..    Bed               6
```

### Total Sheet

```
    A         B    
  Quality    12    (2*1 + 5*2 + 6*0 )
  Confort    25    (2*1 + 5*1 + 6*3 )
```

I'm pretty sur I have the hardest part done. I can check and grab the quantity from all the sheets I want. I also got a function done where you pass the name of the item, and the stats name, and it return me the results I want.

so, I got this part of the code atm which doesnt work, and its driving me nuts.

```
 For Counter = 12 To 42 Step 2
     For Each qColumn In QTYColumn

       Set QTY = Range(qColumn & Counter)
       Dim ItemName As Range
       ItemName= QTY.Offset(-2, 0).Select

       total = total + (QTY * GetValue(ItemName, "Confort"))
    Next qColumn 
Next Counter
```

My problem is with the ItemName variable. Its always empty and as soon as I get to it with the debugger, the function stops and it closes. Anyone have any idea as to why ? it's important for me to get it base on the offset -2 and not the column adress  because it might be different depending of the sheet, and the only "sure" way to find it is the get the 2nd cell to the left of the quantity cell.

Comment: well, I'm going to eat at my parents. I'll be back in a couple of hours and answer any questions or stuff I might have written "wrong"

Comment: Second cell to the left should be `QTY.Offset(0, -2).Select`?

Comment: Put `On Error Goto ErrHandler` at the top, and add `ErrHandler: If Err.Number <> 0 Then Stop` at the bottom. A function that just exits looks like a function that's failing, you need to get `Err.Description` to get a clue. Probably your range address is invalid.

Comment: Why on earth is that `.Select` even there?

Comment: as for the .select, I'm not sure. I've been trying for a while and mix up a bunch of exemple. I think it was to switch the active cell ... but I cant recall

Comment: aaa loannis thanks ! Dont know why those 2 offset parameters are this way, it seems like they are inverted in my mind,  but at least now I'm getting the name I wanted

Comment: [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: thanks, thats a great topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ItemName= QTY.Offset(-2, 0).Select` does not mean anything !

Either you Select:
    `QTY.Offset(-2, 0).Select`

or you get the value:
    `ItemName= QTY.Offset(-2, 0).Value` '(value can be omitted here)
But then, `Dim ItemName As Range` does not make sense. It should be a `String` or a a number.

or you get the range:
    `Set ItemName= QTY.Offset(-2, 0)`  ' then you need `Set`

Comment: excellent, with this and loannis comments I got it to work finally !